# docker 1.9.1,, doesn't stop docker container

Tags: docker, containers, centos7

Dockerfile :

```
...
VOLUME [ “/sys/fs/cgroup” ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

I build & run my centos7 docker container on Centos7.

> $ docker run --privileged -ti -d -e "container=docker" --name
>   centos7-server -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup centos7:81ee535
>   **/usr/sbin/init**

after, input below commend

> $ docker stop centos7-server

.. forever loop..

if /usr/sbin/init to /bin/bash, centos7-server be stoped(success) well.

but, I want to use systemd in centos7-server container..

What can cause the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The `sbin/init` program (also called init) coordinates the rest of the boot process and configures the environment for the user.

Using CentOS docker, init always executes before `CMD / ENTRYPOINT`. So, **it has no sense to use init as** `COMMAND` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

Definitively, don't worry about init. Don't launch it with `docker run` nor `docker exec`, because it's going to be executed anyway.
The init program starts all of the background processes by looking in the appropriate rc directory for the runlevel specified as the default in /etc/inittab. The rc directories are numbered to correspond to the runlevel they represent. For instance, /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/ is the directory for runlevel 5. So, it has no sense to stop it unless you shutdown system.